# How can I transform a Result into a Bool in Q# + C# environment?

Tags: q#

I'm writing a Q# program and I'm calling an operation defined in the program that outputs a `Result` (`One` or `Zero`).

For example something like this:

```
output = QuantumOperation.Run(sim).Result;
```

I want to convert now `output` to a `bool` within C#, but I don't know how.

One way to go around this is to change the output of `QuantumOperation` to be a `bool` and transforming the result at the end of the operation with [`ResultAsBool(result)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.convert.resultasbool?view=qsharp-preview). However, I want to maintain the output of the operation to be a `Result`. So ideally the conversion should happen within the C# host code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q# type `Result` is represented by C# class `Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Core.Result`; in particular, it has constants `Result.Zero` and `Result.One` that you can compare the return of your operation to.

```
using Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Core;

boolOutput = (QuantumOperation.Run(sim).Result == Result.One);
```